# Cannot place shape in Chart tab with Aspose.Cells

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose-cells

I'm trying to insert a watermark on a Workbook, but I can't place the watermark on chart elements. This is my code:

```
Aspose.Cells.Drawing.Shape wordart = sheet.Shapes.AddTextEffect(MsoPresetTextEffect.TextEffect1,
            text, "Arial Black", 50, true, false
            , 0, 200, 0, 100, 97 * (text.Count(x => x == '\n') + 1), 49 * 25);

            MsoFillFormat wordArtFormat = wordart.FillFormat;
            wordArtFormat.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            wordart.RotationAngle = -40;
            wordart.IsTextWrapped = false;
            wordArtFormat.Transparency = 1 - 0.7;
            wordart.X = 000;
            wordart.Y = 300;

            wordart.ZOrderPosition = 30;
            MsoLineFormat lineFormat = wordart.LineFormat;
            lineFormat.IsVisible = false;

            foreach (var chart in sheet.Charts)
            {

                Aspose.Cells.Drawing.Shape wordart2 = chart.Shapes.AddTextEffectInChart(MsoPresetTextEffect.TextEffect1,
                    text, "Arial Black", 50, true, false
                    , 0, 0, 97 * (text.Count(x => x == '\n') + 1), 49 * 25);

                MsoFillFormat wordArtFormat2 = wordart2.FillFormat;
                wordArtFormat2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                wordart2.RotationAngle = -40;
                wordart2.IsTextWrapped = false;
                wordArtFormat2.Transparency = 1 - 0.7;
                wordart2.X = 000;
                wordart2.Y = 300;

                wordart2.ZOrderPosition = 30;
                MsoLineFormat lineFormat2 = wordart2.LineFormat;
                lineFormat2.IsVisible = false;


            }
```

The watermark works fine with the Spreadsheets, but nothing shows up on Charts.

Comment: We have executed your code and found the issue as you described. The watermark gets inserted in Sheet but not in Charts. However, we need to investigate this issue further. We will update you asap. --- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: We have logged your issue in our database for investigation and for a fix. This issue has been logged as CELLSNET-46140. Once, we will have some news for you, we will update you here asap.

Answer (score 0):

**Update - 2**

This issue has been fixed in June release i.e. 18.6 which will be published on NuGet around 15-20th June, 2018. However, you can download the **HotFix** from the following link.

- [Aspose.Cells for .NET 4.0 - 18.5.4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue595ya6utrfeeo/Aspose.Cells18.5.4%20For%20.Net4.0.Zip?dl=0)
- [Aspose.Cells for .NET 2.0 - 18.5.4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s762bv3dnzdmibh/Aspose.Cells18.5.4%20For%20.Net2_AuthenticodeSigned.Zip?dl=0)

---

**Update - 1**

This issue was occurring because of the following line.

```
wordart2.RotationAngle = -40;
```

If it is removed, everything works fine.

When we set the rotation of the shape, we have to re-calculate the position of the shape and there is a problem when we re-calculate the position of the shape in the chart.

---

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose